# FFMPEG fails to convert to usable x265 MP4 after reinstalling Windows/flashing BIOS

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the following command to convert videos recorded by Nvidia ShadowPlay to x265:

`ffmpeg -i "%fn%.mp4" -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "%fn%.x265.mp4"`

I've done this for the past year+ with no problems.  Recently I reinstalled Windows,  flashed my BIOS, and obviously reinstalled ShadowPlay.  Now whenever I run this command against these MP4 files, despite there not being any errors in the console, it creates a corrupt, unplayable file that is dramatically smaller than expected (tried in MPC-HC and MPV).  Files I converted prior to reinstalling still play fine in these players.

I'm sort of at a loss as to what to do without any errors and MPC-HC just says "Cannot render the file", but I don't see how to get any extra information (in a log or whatever).  I grabbed the latest ffmpeg (4.2.1) as I was using 4.1.3 before this, but it made no difference.

Any ideas?  Are there other easy to use command line x265 converters?

Here's the output of converting a 10gb file.  I'm using the `-ss` switch as I have in the past, but it does the same even without it.

```
C:\Users\langdonx\Videos>set fn=s11w3oct31-nov6

C:\Users\langdonx\Videos>ffmpeg -i "s11w3oct31-nov6.mp4" -ss 5:04 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "s11w3oct31-nov6.x265.mp4"
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 's11w3oct31-nov6.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:24:09.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 57968 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 57764 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.0_Au+21-bac0e1acb874
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 8.3.1][64 bit] 8bit+10bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-4 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 12 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 3 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / on / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-28.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 rskip signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: lslices=6 deblock sao
Output #0, mp4, to 's11w3oct31-nov6.x265.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (libx265) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx265
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame= 7634 fps= 17 q=-0.0 size=  183296kB time=00:04:15.07 bitrate=5886.8kbits/s speed=0.579x
C:\Users\langdonx\Videos>echo.


C:\Users\langdonx\Videos>echo COMPLETE!
COMPLETE!

C:\Users\langdonx\Videos>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

ffplay output:

```
ffplay sw.x265.mp4
ffplay version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000019655161240] moov atom not found0
sw.x265.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

mpv output:

```
C:\Users\langdonx\Downloads\mpv-x86_64-20191215-git-2dbe33c>mpv sw.x265.mp4
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: moov atom not found
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: moov atom not found
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
Failed to recognize file format.
```

Why would ffmpeg create these broken files but not report anything in the output?  Do I need to enable some hardware feature in my BIOS?  ffmpeg itself supports the AAC codec I'm using right, or do I need to install one somehow?

Comment: Does ffplay it? What's the log of mpv?

Comment: @Gyan Didn't even think to try ffplay... I added ffplay and mpv output to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -i in -c copy out.mp4` produce a playable file?

Comment: Yes, with the same length and size as the original.

Comment: Since it takes so long to convert something and end up in a failure state, I've taken my smallest file (6:32 @ 2.48gb) and I'm running some isolated tests against it. I cropped it down to 2 minutes with `-copy` and when I convert that, it produces a playable file.  Using `-ss 0:00 -to 0:30` also produces a playable file.  I'll see if I can figure out which conditions fail.

Comment: It seems to fail at random... I did the first 4m30s and it worked... and every a few further tests, returned to do another 4m30s test and it failed.  Maybe I need to run memtest?

Comment: @Gyan I changed the output container from mp4 to mkv and ran my 4m30s test again... the file is playable but it's only 2:02 long...

Comment: Yes, I suspect a HW failure mode.

Comment: I'll run memtest, but mkv is seemingly working 100% without fail now.  Are there certain requirements for mp4 (memory, disk, etc) that mkv output doesn't need?

Comment: Not really; main difference is ffmpeg writes the MP4 metadata after all the media data is written.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  I've converted 8 or so files, all of the mkv files are playable (I guess, obviously), but some are shorter than the original.  It looks like ffmpeg is dying somewhere along the way but not throwing any errors in the console.  Trying to glean some information from changing the loglevel.  Still need to make a bootable thumbdrive with memtest86.